# How to change DNS for eth0?

Tags: linux, networking, dns

Root user:

`systemd-resolve --status`

Output:

```
Global
          DNS Domain: openstacklocal
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.16.2
                      192.168.16.3
          DNS Domain: openstacklocal
```

I need to change DNS for eth0. What I did:

```
cd /etc/systemd/network
nano 20-wired.network
```

Input:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DNS=1.1.1.1, 192.168.16.2, 192.168.16.3
```

Saved.

```
service systemd-networkd restart
service systemd-resolved restart
```

Then: `systemd-resolve --status`

Nothing changed. What did I do wrong? How do I change eth0's DNS? Also:

`systemd-resolve --interface eth0 --set-dns 1.1.1.1`

This outputs:

`Please configure DNS settings for systemd-networkd managed interfaces directly in their .network files.`